# Separating a Word Doc per paragraph on separate page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large word doc with a bunch of songs. There are multiple songs per page. I want to take each song and put it on its own separate page, titling each page with the name of that song. Here is an example:

```
LORD I WORSHIP YOU

F          Am     Bb           C          F       Am    Bb          C 
Lord     I      praise    you,    Lord     I    praise    you

F          Am     Eb           D                Gm                  C            F
Lord     I    praise    you,       I    praise    your   holy    name  

F          Am     Bb           C          F         Am      Bb             C 
Lord     I   worship    you,    Lord       I     worship    you

F          Am      Eb          D                           Gm                       C           F
Lord     I    worship   you,    Lord   I    worship     your   holy    name



AS LONG AS I HAVE BREATH
 G/A                                      D
As        long   as    I    have    breath,   I    will    praise    You    Lord
                                        A                                      G   D                                      
As   long  as   I   can   sing,    I    will   sing   Your    praise
(A)                       D                                     Bm
Wherever   you   lead   I   will    follow    You
                                           A                                                      D
As   long   as  I   have   breath,   I    will    praise   You    Lord




GREAT PRAISE – GREAT GOD
D             D/F#                   G         G/E            D/A                                     A          Gm/A  G/B  A
Great   praise   for   a   great   God   A  mighty  worship  for  the  Mighty One
D                          D/F#                 G                       Em                                     
We  bring  you  worship  and  we  bring  you  praise  
D/F#     Em/G    D/A                 A7     D/A              Em/A    Em/D     D       
We    bring    great  praise,  great  praise   for    a      great   God
```

I would like Lord I Worship you on a separate page, As Long as I have Breath on a separate page, and Great Praise - Great God on a separate page. With each page I would like to use the title of each song as the title of the document.

Is this possible?

Comment: You say "separate page" all the way until the end, where you say "the document." Pages and documents are different things. If you are just interested in pages, do a find and replace, replacing two paragraph breaks with a page break, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking two different questions. I'll define each question and answer it accordingly.

At first, you say you want each song on a different page and title "each ***page*** with the name of the song". I take that to mean, each page within a single document or file. In MS Word, after each song, hit the control and enter keys at the same time. This will go to the next line and create a page break so each song is on its on page. This will put each song on its own page within the document. To find a song, you can either scroll through the whole document or hit  + f to open the find box and type in the title of the song you want.

At the end, you mention that you "would like to use the title of each song as the title of the ***document***". I take that to mean, you want each song in its own document or file. If that's the case, then you should create a separate document (a new file) for each song. Just open up a new or blank document and use copy and paste to put one song in the new document. Save the new document with the title of the song as the name of the document. Close the document and open another new or blank document. Repeat the procedure with each song.